# How to handle os.TransactionTooLargeException in android

Tags: android, google-maps

### Hi I am passing Bitmap Image to MapActivity of my app through intent.it work fine for some devices for some device it shows an error: Exception when starting activity com.primesys.mitra/.ShowGMap 06-19 15:20:12.566: W/ActivityManager(943): android.os.TransactionTooLargeException channel '33660a3d com.primesys.mitra/com.primesys.mitra.TrackNewActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. events=0x9 My intent passing code is try{ pos=(Integer)v.getTag(); Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShowGMap.class); BitmapDrawable bitmap_draw=(BitmapDrawable)pro_pic.getDrawable(); G_image=bitmap_draw.getBitmap(); intent.putExtra("G_image", G_image); intent.putExtra("deviceId",data.get(pos).getDeviceid()); intent.putExtra("StudentId",data.get(pos).getStudentId()); ((Activity)context).startActivity(intent); }catch(Exception ex) { Log.e("Exception ", ""+ex); }

Comment: save your Bitmap somewhere and pass its path as an intent extra

Answer (score 0):

You can pass small data with `intents`,
Use `SharedPreferences` for passing data between activities.